# How can I stop facebook's notification about continuous contact uploads?

Tags: notifications, facebook

Every day I receive something along the lines of this (often it's just "1 new notification"):

[image]

Seem pretty exciting, maybe I should see what it is. But it turns out it's just facebook pestering me to fork over my contacts list and takes me straight to this page:

[image]

There seems to be no way to say "no". Either I turn this feature on or I have a daily notification from facebook. Is there a workaround?

If I can't stop it, I guess I'll just uninstall the app. The only reason I have it is to get infrequent notifications and if most of the time it's spam it's not useful to me.

Some people have suggested accepting the contacts upload and then disabling the feature. However the notification comes straight back. Also, this isn't a solution for the people who don't want facebook to have their contacts at all.

Not sure if this is the right place to ask. If not, where's appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the downward pointing arrow on desktop and then go to settings and then go to notifications you should be able to turn it off or tweak it there. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Edit your post to include screenshots (annotated or cropped) to give detail to your answer, it's always difficult to navigate menus without visuals to go by.

Comment: I've been through all the notifications settings I can find in both android's and facebook's but can't see anything relevant.